# synapseml lightgbm model doesn't converge on Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, azure-synapse, lightgbm

I'm trying to deploy a gbdt model with synapseml lightgbm[0.9.5] on google dataproc[2.0-debian10].
I use Spark StringIndexer to index string categorical columns and assemble all columns as a vector. With categorical features setting, I found the model error doesn't converge and  there are lots of warnings:

`DEFAULT    [LightGBM] [Warning] Met negative value in categorical features, will convert it to NaN`

It's strange that I checked all categorical features are in [0.0, 72234.0] which are in the range of Int32 https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1359

Then I removed the categorical meta info and treat all features as numeric features. The warning is gone but the metric seems still wierd.

[lightgbm valid metric in logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ2Os.jpg)

The model works on local spark environment. So I guess there is something wrong with data shared from JVM to C on DataProc.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Is it possible to share your code and sample data here?